Azure What-If operation resource change type
I want to create an Azure what if operation in subscription scope to recognize the resources that have been created after a Bicep deployment. The problem is that when I run the command az deployment sub what-if --result-format FullResourcePayloads -f deploy.main.bicep --location "westeurope" -p @deploy.main.parameters.stg.json, I get all the resource groups as NoChange and all the resources in every resource group scope as Ignored. Is there any way to get NoChange change type to resources in this scenario?
Note: I want to execute the command after the deployment
If you have any other way to recognize all the resource names of a bicep deployment after the deployment it would be very useful.

Edit (1/4/2024):
Please answer to this: If I set the Deployment Mode to Complete, will this delete the resources that are not included in the deployment in the what-if operation?

Edit (2/4/2024):
After some research I found that we cannot have Complete deployment mode in subscription deployments, so I still need a way to get the resources that are included in a deployment after the actual deployment

If use 'what-if', no resource will be actually deleted even using 'Complete' mode. but will show you which resources be deleted if you remove 'what-if' after the command.

ok I found that we cannot have Complete mode in subscription deployments and in nested deployments, so I cannot filter the resources of the deployment using this. Any idea of how can I get the names of the resources that are included in a subscription deployment after the actual deployment?

Any approach is fine for you to get the names of the resources that are included in a subscription or only bicep? @SotirisSotiriou

I want to get all the resource names of a bicep deployment. This deployment have also nested deployments. Keep that in mind.


If I set the Deployment Mode to Complete, will this delete the resources that are not included in the deployment in the what-if operation?

To answer your issue, the 'Complete' deployment mode is primarily used for deployments targeting resource groups rather than subscriptions, as you also mentioned in update.

Azure Resource Manager provides the what-if operation to let you see how resources will change if you deploy the Bicep file.

When I try to deploy a sample bicep code at subscription deployment, it was deployed as shown below with the command.
az deployment sub what-if --result-format FullResourcePayloads -f rg.bicep --location "westeurope"


Alternatively, as a workaround use resource graph query or CLI by filtering it with creation date to check the post deployment related changes in the code.
az deployment sub list -o table

You can also below command to filter it with an exact timestamp.
az deployment sub list --query "[?properties.timestamp == 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ']"

